# Red squiggly line in Maven dependency list in IntelliJ - where do I start debugging?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm getting a red squiggly line under the maven dependency to `play-services-maps`, a library that is installed locally with the M2 repository coming with the Android SDK. I've configured it correcly as a local repository in maven. The dependency is resolved when I look at the XML file, but the "Maven projects" tab show otherwise and the project does not compile (classes from the AAR is not found).

Where do I even start looking for the error? Why is it not presenting an error message with the squiggly line?

[image: Intellij]

I've looked in `idea.log` but nothing. The dependency graph looks ok as well:

[image: dependency graph]

Any hints?

I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.2

*edit*: After running `mvn install` from the command line I realised it attempted to fetch the dependency as a .jar. It is a .aar, so adding `<type>aar</type>` to the dependency specification fixed it

Comment: does `mvn install` work from command line?

Comment: No it didn't but it gave me the info that I needed! Write that as an answer and I'll accept it :) (I'm such a visual IDE-geek that it didn't occur to me to run the command line tool)

Comment: Thanks :) I would report a bug, that red line should have a tooltip. It seems that some transitive dependency was not resolved, right? You would maybe see that in the pom of *play-services-maps*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute `mvn install` from command line, or from IntelliJ directly, to see details. Or you could try hovering over the module...

[image]

Comment: The "hover" advice helps in other parts of IntelliJ, too!

Answer (score 0):

[image: intellij refresh]

Click on this refresh button. This reimports all maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

Close the project and import project again by selecting the POM file

Answer (score -1):

The only solution that woked for me is downloading .jar file of dependency, placing it directly in the project. Dependency changed to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bad.robot</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-excel</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/resources/libs/simple-excel-1.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```